# React / Redux - how to render/update deeply nested sate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'll get from the API a deeply nested state - e.g.:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "text": "test",
    "children": [{
        "id": 1,
        "text": "test",
        "children": [{
            "id": 1,
            "text": "test",
            "children": [{
                "id": 1,
                "text": "test",
                "children": []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

(Please ignore duplicate ids etc)

Now here are the requirements:

- I need to properly render this

e.g.

```
<div>
text
  <div>
   text
  </div>
</div>
```

- I need to be able to update the nested state within redux store
- This list can be huge - like at least 3k items (which theoretically works fine)

What I tried:

Having everything unnested:

- Rendering is very complicated (with parentId)
- Maintaining the structure is difficult (need to flatten and unflatten it) -> this costs a lot of performance

Having everything nested:

- Updating the store is impossible without "cheating" in react -> manipulating the state directly

What can be a solution to this? What should be the architecture

Comment: I don't have very concrete recommendation but I'd look further into flattening the redux state with something like `normalizr` and using a unique `id` as the `children` property. I imagine that will make updating state more efficient. When you need the data structure associated to `children`, you look it up with `id` in the flat redux store.

Comment: The issue with normalizing is the performance - it is very expensive for bigger objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) will probably be of use to you here.

```
const state = [{
    "id": 1,
    "text": "test",
    "children": [{
        "id": 1,
        "text": "test",
        "children": [{
            "id": 1,
            "text": "test",
            "children": [{
                "id": 1,
                "text": "test",
                "children": []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}];

const newState = update(state, { 
    0: { 
      children: { 
        0: {
          children {
            0 : {
              children: {
                0: { 
                  "id": { $set: 2}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
   };

return newState;

[{
    "id": 1,
    "text": "test",
    "children": [{
        "id": 1,
        "text": "test",
        "children": [{
            "id": 1,
            "text": "test",
            "children": [{
                "id": 2,
                "text": "test",
                "children": []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}];
```

The `0`s here could be replaced with some indexes in your `payload`; I just used 0 here as the example arrays all have only 1 element in them. This is quite deeply nested though so as the comments pointed out, any flattening you can do will make the updates easier.

Comment: Thanks. A better solution is actually using immer - makes it easier ;)